# How to see just content of ZIP/RAR etc withoud downloading?

Tags: firefox, compression, zip, rar

How to see just content of ZIP/RAR etc without downloading?

for example like this http://dev.novemberborn.net/sifr3/nightlies/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[LoadScout](http://www.loadscout.com/)** - Download Selected Files, Extract Information and Snatch Parts From Remote Media-Files And Archives

[image]

There's also a Firefox addon for you:

**[ArchView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5028)** can open archive file online without downloading the whole archive. Just like normal web pages. It is very fast since it merely fetches a small portion of the archive file from server

[image]

Comment: i just want  see content with right click , something like this http://www.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/javascript_source_code.jpg is it possible?